# No performance improvement using --jobs parameter for pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am using [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html) to restore the Postgresql database backed up using [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html). (both the backup and restore is happening on PostgreSQL 12). The backup is taken using the custom format option `--format=custom`.

The restore for 10 GB backup is taking almost 30 mins. The time to restore increases significantly as the size of the backup increases. So I tried out the `--jobs` parameter for improving the restore times.

As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html), concurrent connections will be used to restore the database objects. I verified the output of restore and I could verify that there were parallel threads started equal to the value of the `--jobs` parameter. However the time to restore has not improved with any value of the `--jobs` parameter.

I am aware that the performance depends on the hardware infrastructure. But the machine has 16 vcpus and 32GB RAM.

I have also tried tuning Postgres as mentioned in the [blog](https://www.tutorialdba.com/2017/11/improve-performance-of-pgdump-pgrestore.html) with following configurations but still no improvements in restore times.

```
    work_mem = 32MB
    shared_buffers = 4GB
    maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
    full_page_writes = off
    autovacuum = off
    wal_buffers = -1
```

Is there anything that I have missed? How do I get an improvement in the restore time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that could be the problem:

- `pg_restore` parallelizes by running several `COPY` and `CREATE INDEX` commands concurrently.

  Now if your database has one large table with a single large index, parallelization won't help you.
- Perhaps your I/O system is at its limit.  Then running processes in parallel won't improve the performance.
- If you have lots of large objects, that is known to slow down processing, and I am not sure if parallelization helps or not.

Don't ever set `full_page_writes` or `autovacuum` to `off` unless you set them back to `on` after restore and are ready to dump the database cluster in the event of a crash. I doubt that the performance gain is worth it, particularly for `full_page_writes`.

One parameter that you forgot is `max_wal_size`. If you raise that, it will help write performance.

Apart from that, you have to find out where the bottleneck is before you can fix it.

How about using a different backup method like `pg_basebackup` that is normally faster?

Comment: There is one table which has references to blob oids.  Most of the backup size is the size of these blobs. There are not many large tables in terms of records present. Can this  be hindering the performance ?

and any pointer to how can I verify if I/O is the bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, large objects are slow to restore, and there is no parallelization for them. This is certainly the reason. I will extend the answer.

Comment: Thanks @laurenz. The reason we are using pg_dump is because of some business use cases where we need to do selective schema restores from the backup. pg_basebackup would not allow me to do that.

Comment: Also for reference is there any public documentation that states that blobs cannot be parallelized?

Comment: No. Actually, I am not 100% certain, so I changed the answer. A quick peek at the code did not enlighten me. But I have seen complaints about slow restore with many large objects before.